# Swift Object never able to put value inside it

Tags: ios, swift, object

I have an object named newMovieVar of type Movie.
Below I have the object declaration.

```
import Foundation

class Movie: NSObject {
var moviePoster: String = ""
var movieName: String = ""
}
```

In the view controller where I use this object, I declare it like this:

```
 var newMovieVar: Movie!
```

And then I try to set values in it

```
newMovieVar?.moviePoster = "bla bla"
newMovieVar?.movieName = "bla bla bla"
```

But whenever I try to print the values from newMovieVar, I get *nil*:

```
print(newMovieVar?.moviePoster)
print(newMovieVar?.movieName)
```

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Alloc/init of `newMovieVar`?

Comment: With `var newMovieVar: Movie!`, your `newMovieVar` is still `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring a variable of type `Movie` but you are not giving it a value. You need to create a new `Movie` object and assign it to your variable so there is a value for you to work with.

```
var newMovieVar = Movie()
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not initializing `newMovieVar` before assigning to its properties:

```
var newMovieVar = Movie()

newMovieVar.moviePoster = "bla bla"
newMovieVar.movieName = "bla bla bla"

print(newMovieVar.moviePoster) // "bla bla"
print(newMovieVar.movieName) // "bla bla bla"
```

Answer (score 2):

it's because you never initialize your object:

Try something like this :

```
var newMovieVar = Movie()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also provide the initializers in the `init()` function and create the Movie directly with the initial values like this:

```
class Movie: NSObject {
    var moviePoster: String
    var movieName: String

    init(moviePoster: String, movieName: String){
        self.moviePoster = moviePoster
        self.movieName = movieName
    }

}

var newMovieVar = Movie(moviePoster: "bla bla", movieName: "bla bla bla")

print(newMovieVar.moviePoster) // "bla bla"
print(newMovieVar.movieName) // "bla bla bla"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a Movie object before you use it. 
Please follow the below code:

```
var movie = Movie()
```